# Facebook Enhanced Auth Dialog - how to display?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm looking for a way to show the facebook enhanced dialog box so I can explain to users why they are giving my app permissions.

My url for permissions looks like this:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=xxx&redirect_uri=xxx&scope=email,user_location
```

And my permissions box looks like this:

[image]

However I want my dialog to look like this:

[image]

How to I change this? I've set the values of the fields as they have in [this post](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/03/02/enhanced-auth-dialog-and-updates-to-permissions/) but I still get the first dialog box.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm mistaken, the enhanced auth dialog is no more or rather... it has been streamlined as referenced by this post https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/12/12/providing-people-greater-clarity-and-control/

[image: Run With Friends]

As seen above the app "Run with Friends" no longer shows the enhanced dialog.

Comment: Hrm, looks like you are right. I still have access to the fields, but we aren't able to display them in any way?

Comment: @wes I believe those fields are for your app detail page in the center.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/, may be you should send you app to review.